# Все связанные записи в cgridview

Tags: cgridview, yii

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица марок машин и таблица их моделей (связь один ко многим). Хочу сделать, чтоб в гриде марок было поле "Модели" и в нем скажем через запятую были все связанные модели данной марки. Как это провернуть? Где мне сгенерировать эту строку и дать "съесть" ее гриду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

> 'columns' => array(
>
> ```
> ...
>
> array(
>
>     'name' => 'Модели',
>
>     'value' => join(', ', array_map(function($item){
>
>         return $item->title;
>
>     }, $data->models))
>
> ),
>
> ... ),
> ```

Comment: @VasyOk, спасибо) Работает. Я вот нарыл еще один метод:  
  ...
    'value'=>'$data->getModelsById()',
  ...  
  
Метод getModelsById():  
  
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = '*';
        $criteria->condition = 'id_mark = :id_mark';
        $criteria->params = array(':id_mark'=>$this->id);

        $models = CarModel::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $arr = CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'name');

        return implode(", ", $arr);